# Iterate through a stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am working on a question.

Use a `stack` to process parenthesized expressions. When you seen an open parenthesis, note that it was seen. When you see a close parenthesis after an open parenthesis, `pop` elements down to and including the open parenthesis of the `stack`. `push` a value onto the `stack` to indicate that a parenthesized expression was replaced.

How is this even possible? This would require to iterate through a `stack`. For instance, if the stack was composed of `char`s and initialized with

```
This is just (a test) to see.
```

I can `pop` off the top until I see a closed parenthesis and store each word and `push_front` into a different container, etc. And then copy back into a `stack` but that is indirectly solving the problem. I don't understand how you can answer the problem without iterating through the `stack` and from my understanding `stack` does not use iterators or subscripts so how is that possible?

Comment: You can't iterate over a conventional stack, but you can copy the stack into a vector or string and then do what you like. But this probably defeats the purpose of the exercise ;)

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: Seconding Neil's comment and adding that you may be thinking too literally about the statement/question.  I'm assuming this relates to parsing math expressions, so perhaps thinking about it in terms of operators and operands in the stack instead of an array of characters might help.

Comment: @DarylHanson. Could elaborate just a bit more?

Comment: "push a value" definitely implies math expressions. You do not iterate. I believe when you see a close parenthesis you need to pop all elements to first opening parenthesis and count value of expression inside this parenthesis and then push it on stack and go to next elements.

Comment: I love how you commented on your own question!?

Comment: @NeilKirk. The original question!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the only element visible on a stack is the top of the stack.  Formally, at least, and `std::stack` enforces this.  Practically, it's often useful to be able to see a little bit deeper, or even iterate; in such cases, you just don't use `std::stack`.  (`std::vector` with `push_back`, `pop_back` and `back` makes a very good stack, for example.

Alternatively, the underlying data member of `std::stack` is only protected, not private, so you can inherit from `std::stack`, and add all of the additional members you way.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. OP seems to be aware of how stack works. The real problem is understanding given task in terms of stack.

Answer (score 1):

No, the original question doesn't ask you to iterate through a stack even though I agree that the original question could be more clearer.

Let's take an example expression:
  (8-(1+2))/5
= (8-3)/5
= 5/5
= 1

How can we achieve this?
We start reading from the leftmost element (digit, operator or parenthesis), and push them into a stack. When we see an opening parenthesis, we increment parenthesis_counter. When we see a closing parenthesis, we do not push the closing parenthesis into the stack but rather, start popping elements from the stack down to and including the most recent opening parenthesis, decrement the parenthesis_counter; The items that we pop, we store them all except the parenthesis in another vector or container, evaluate them and push the result into the stack. We continue reading the elements left.

So, in the above example, until we read the first closing parenthesis, we have:
(8-(1+2
at this point, parenthesis_counter = 2 and I have pushed all the elements into the stack as it is.
Now I encounter a closing parenthesis, I don't push it. I pop elements '2', '+', '1', and '('; decrement parenthesis_counter by 1, evaluate 1+2 which returns 3. Hence I push 3 into the stack.

So, now I have
(8-3
at this point, parenthesis_counter = 1. I continue to read the rest of the elements.

EDIT: Please note that, parenthesis_counter has nothing to do with the solution, it is there only to aid the explanation states.

Comment: What is the purpose of parenthesis_counter? It gets incremented and decremented, but nothing seems to depend on its value.

Comment: @PeteBecker, You are right. Parenthesis_counter has nothing to do with the solution. I used it for explaining. I may delete it from the main solution but then it may be unclear to explain the state later. Let me mention it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: On a second thought, parenthesis_counter may help you to detect illegal expressions (not done here). And I guess, I included it in the first place because the exercise question says: "When you seen an open parenthesis, note that it was seen."